# Create three column layout, using unknown number of items from the database

Tags: jquery, math, jquery-mobile

This should be an easy one, it probably just involves math. I have a three column layout, and I'd like to append jQuery collapsible divs for each item returned from my database.

Example: If I return 9 items from the database:

```
column 1 = 1, 4, 7
column 2 = 2, 5, 8
column 3 = 3, 6, 9
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
if (centerCount == 1 || centerCount == 4 || centerCount == 7)
{   
// add to column 1                  
}
else if (centerCount == 2 || centerCount == 5 || centerCount == 8)
{
    // add to column 2
}
else if (centerCount == 3 || centerCount == 6 || centerCount == 9)
{
    // add to column 3
}
```

The above is assuming the number of items is 9. How would I do it if I had no idea what number of items would be returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have some consecutive id (like, I assume, your `centerCount`), you can use the following code with the modulo operator `%`:

```
var col = centerCount % 3;

switch( col ) {
  case 0: // first column
    break;
  case 1: // second column
    break;
  case 2: // third column
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

very simple modulus will do the trick

```
if (centerCount % 3 == 1) {
    // add to column 1
} 
else if (centerCount % 3 == 2) {
    // add to column 2
} 
else if (centerCount % 3 == 0) {
    // add to column 3
}
```

Comment: Looks like Sirko beat me to the post button. I can't comment on anything but my own content yet but Sirko has a small issue. According to the question 3, 6, 9 should be in column 3.. in Sirko's solution they will actually end up in column 1

Comment: The issue depends on where to start the counting. In IT most lists start with index 0, which is what I suppose in my solution. Yet both are valid, but you're right: According to OP's question your solution is correcter ,-)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this plugin? **Columnizer jQuery Plugin**

- http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/
- https://github.com/adamwulf/Columnizer-jQuery-Plugin

not sure if it will meet your needs?

Answer (score 0):

```
var col = centerCount % 3;

switch( col ) {
  case 1: // first column
    break;
  case 2: // second column
    break;
  case 0: // third column
    break;
}
```

Comment: This answer is very very similar to the accepted answer. Yes you switched the cases around, you should explain exactly why you have done that.

Comment: Lets run it. if `centerCount` is 3 then it should be placed in 3rd column, however, the accepted answer would place it in 1st column i.e. 3%3 = 0

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do, just iterate over each column, and then iterate over each value of each column. This seems like the final solution you're trying to get to.

```
<?
$columns = array(
    array(1,4,7,5,34,5,5),
    array(2,5,6,5,3,6,2),
    array(3,6,9,5,4,3,2)
)
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <? for($x = 0; $x < count($columns); $x++) { ?>
        <td>
            <? foreach($columns[$x] as $column_value) { ?>
            <?= $column_value ?><br />
            <? } ?>
        </td>
        <? } ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `slice()` in conjunction with `wrapAll` to wrap the elements in column wrapper so you don't need to create any arrays, just do the calcs based on total items

```
var $divs = $('#content div');
var totDiv = $divs.length,
    start = 0,
    itemsPerColumn = Math.ceil(totDiv / 3);

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var end = start + itemsPerDiv;
    $divs.slice(start, end).wrapAll('<div class="column">')
    start = end
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/WHNgP/

Alternatively if you are creating the elements from an array of data do the same on the array using native javascript slice while creating the html

API refrence: http://api.jquery.com/slice/